# Optimize search efficiency with mongoDB nested collection?

Tags: mongodb, document-oriented-db

Let us suppose we have the next data structure:

```
{
    {
    "name" : "ElementName1",

    "index" : [
         {"name" : "key1", "value" : 1},
         {"name" : "key2", "value" : 2},
         {"name" : "key3", "value" : 3}
        ]
    },
    {
    "name" : "ElementName2",
    "index" : [
         {"name" : "key1", "value" : 3},
         {"name" : "key2", "value" : 2},
         {"name" : "key3", "value" : 7}
        ]
    },
}
```

The idea is to have the best read performance possible. Let us suppose the priority on searching by name, so we ensure an ascending index on name (actually I've written a prototype and index considerably increases the search speed. This decreases the time for search from 1-2 sec to 0,1 sec for a million of really large documents.) The idea is to index the nested array fields somehow, but the problem is from what they write [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/f6c1c99691d1582c/fd78464898cfce2a), it is somehow impossible. I am trying to implement it using **mongodb-csharp** combination, but I suggest we do not specify the language. What are the possible increase options as I see:

1. Implement this index in a way I am not yet aware of.
2. Create one more collection for those array nested fields and index it in there.
3. Other options.

Please share your view and ideas.

Comment: Isn't the linked issue only related to unique=true indexes? There's no reason why you wouldn't index the arrays other than memory use.

Comment: I managed to index them but the result hardly impressed me.

Comment: The options available to you are indexing appropriately (mind you, adding an index for just the array will not do anything) or re-engineering your schema to something that better fits your use case.

Comment: If we talk about indexing appropriately, what options beyond indexing the whole document and indexing with compound keys(index.name, index.keys) do I have?

Comment: If your example is the entire document you're basically indexing the whole thing. That's not exactly ideal. That said it will make your queries use covered indexes. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes for details. If that isn't an option you will need to change your schema.